# When does a good graphics card help in Mathematica

Tags: plotting, graphics, performance-tuning, system-performance, hardware

I've got an NVIDIA GTX 960 and 32G RAM on my desktop. I was just wondering if it really does any benifit to the usage of Mathematica compared with some integrated card in high-end intel chips.

I often `Plot3D` surfaces or vector fields (sometimes from big numerical data like 1 or 2MB generated by Mathematica or others) and drag and rotate them.
I also sweep some parameter range and generate like 50 2D line plots to make `Animate` or `Manipulate` saved within the Notebook. Often the plot takes more time than the computation especially as I scale up the calculation/data size. When I reopen the Notebook, such saved plots take seconds to load usually. Not sure if this is normal.
Related, I often `ParallelTable` to sweep parameters and compute complex things without any graphics to generate data for plotting.

Comment: Related: [159411](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/159411). The only thing that I have to add is that at least the builtin functions for machine learning seem to benefit from GPUs.

Comment: I saw wolfram published [this](http://support.wolfram.com/kb/39353) recently, the GPU section might interest you